# moving table data error ‘#1062 - Duplicate entry‘

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '09144269297' for key 'users_number_unique'

I want move table rows of an old database to a new database in MySQL 
with these codes

```
INSERT INTO esdigibonyan.users(id,number,name,lastname)
SELECT id,mobile,name,family FROM d_old.applicants
```

Comment: Are you sure the datatypes of columns are same?

Comment: is identity isert enable for id column?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain yes I'm sure  both of them are varchar

Comment: @fa06 how to check that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard duplicate entries than you can use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO esdigibonyan.users(id,number,name,lastname)
SELECT id,mobile,name,family FROM d_old.applicants
```

If you want to keep duplicate enteries than disable key `users_number_unique` on table `esdigibonyan.users` then insert and then re-enable key.

Comment: the problem is : in  d_old.applicants we don't have any duplicate mobile number